# SQL report - Matching percent value with a number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, obiee

I have a small issue with my report and I need to know if its even possible to do it? 
Im using Oracle12c and the tool OBIEE, im trying to create a **custom column** with numbers values (1 and 2) that are matching my results from my "Percent" column in a way I described below.

Here is my results in table:

[image: My table]

I will give u an example of how it should work:

Emilian is an owner of few customers, the customers have their annual revenue listed and the column next to it its the Percent value of the total customer revenue for Emilian. Now, in my custom column I need to show "1" for customers that contribute more than (or exact) 80% of his total and "2" for the rest. So in Emilian Case, his first two customers will be "1" since 78% + 14% is already above 80% and the rest will be "2". For other Owners that only have one customer, all of them logically would be matched with "1" since their contribution is 100%

Hope I made this clear, will be veery grateful for the help with coding it :)

Alex

Comment: Please don't post an image of SQL. It makes it difficult for anyone to mock it up to help you. Try to recreate your schema and test data. A simple text-based description would help, but if you can, use something like http://dbfiddle.uk or http://sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Im sorry for this, I thought it would help to understand the concept :) All the columns are just selected from a table and there is a calculation for percent value column like (sales/sum(sales))*100. Im asking for the help with making my custom column  for it as I described above :)

Comment: Can you explain `So in Emilian Case, his first two customers will be "1" since 78% + 14% is already above 80% and the rest will be "2".? Why do these get a 1 and not a 2? Technically, first and third customers are also above 80%. And what if you have 5 customers that each contribute 20%? What is your exact requirement?

Comment: Yeah ok: The customers are ranked (with RANK()) from the highest contributor to lowest. In Emilian case just the first two of his customers already exceeds the line of 80% of his total contribution so they would be paired with a value of "1". The 80% line is a key here. If there would be 5 customers, for example ranked with: 30%, 25%, 20%, 10% and 5%, only the last one would be "2" since the 4th one broke the line of 80% (30+25+20+10 = 85 so its above 80). Hope it makes it clear :)

Comment: Yes, but what if they are all tied?

Comment: Then this would be extreme rare case because the data I've shown here is a simple example, normally owner have many customers and their revenue is very different from one another. So even if all 5 would have around 20%, there will always be ones with 20,62%, 20,45% and so on :) In other words, I dont expect such a result here

Comment: Extremely rare cases are the ones that usually end up biting you pretty hard.

Comment: Could you include the table or query that output is generated from?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a much more efficient way to do this. I built up what you need to get at with a series of sub-selects. This still doesn't handle the equal percents, but you said that isn't an expected problem. I'd still watch out for it.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46a50d/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( ownerId int, customerId int, revenue int ) ;

INSERT INTO t1 ( ownerid, customerid, revenue )
SELECT 1, 1, 99 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 300 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4, 400 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 5, 100 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 6, 100 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 7, 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 8, 600 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 9, 100 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 10, 900 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 11, 1000 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 12, 1000 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 13, 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 14, 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 15, 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 16, 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 17, 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 42, 736784, 1480000 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 42, 736580, 280160 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 42, 1040137, 112486 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 42, 738685, 22903 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 42, 736781, 56 FROM dual 
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s3.ownerID, s3.customerID, s3.revenue, s3.OwnerRevenue
  , CAST(s3.customerRevPct AS decimal(5,2)) AS customerRevPct
  , CASE WHEN s3.PctRT < 80 OR s3.custCount = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS customCol
  /* Do the running pcts add up to 80+? 1 customer = 100% == 1. What if all are pcts are equal? */
FROM (
  SELECT s2.*
    , 100-SUM(nvl(s2.customerRevPct,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY s2.ownerID ORDER BY s2.customerRevPct, s2.customerID RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS pctRT
    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s2.ownerID ORDER BY (s2.ownerID) ) AS custCount /* Is there only 1 customer? */
  FROM (
    SELECT s1.*
      , ( ( ( s1.revenue * 1.0 ) / s1.ownerRevenue ) * 100 ) AS customerRevPct 
    FROM (
      SELECT t1.ownerID, t1.customerID, t1.revenue
        ,  SUM(t1.revenue) OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.ownerID ) AS ownerRevenue
      FROM t1
    ) s1
  ) s2
) s3
WHERE ownerID = 42 /* REMOVE THIS LINE - TESTING ONLY */
ORDER BY s3.ownerID, s3.customerRevPct DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46a50d/1/0)**:

```
| OWNERID | CUSTOMERID | REVENUE | OWNERREVENUE | CUSTOMERREVPCT | CUSTOMCOL |
|---------|------------|---------|--------------|----------------|-----------|
|      42 |     736784 | 1480000 |      1895605 |          78.08 |         1 |
|      42 |     736580 |  280160 |      1895605 |          14.78 |         1 |
|      42 |    1040137 |  112486 |      1895605 |           5.93 |         2 |
|      42 |     738685 |   22903 |      1895605 |           1.21 |         2 |
|      42 |     736781 |      56 |      1895605 |              0 |         2 |
```

**EDIT:** I changed the Fiddle to illustrate your data example.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table custrev(owner varchar2(100), cust_id number, revenue number);

insert into custrev values('Emilian',1,1480000);
insert into custrev values('Emilian',2,280160);
insert into custrev values('Emilian',3,112486);
insert into custrev values('Emilian',4,22903);
insert into custrev values('Emilian',5,56);
insert into custrev values('Andy',6,1378);
insert into custrev values('Sandy',7,560000);

commit;
```

Below is the SQL for your requirement.

```
select owner, cust_id, revenue, pct,
       case when pct = 100 then 1
            when flg is null or flg < 80 then 1
            else 2 end flag_col
  from (select owner, cust_id, revenue, pct,--cumulative_sum,
               lag(cumulative_sum) over(partition by owner 
                                        order by revenue desc) flg 
          from (select owner, cust_id, revenue, pct, 
                       sum(pct) over(partition by owner 
                                     order by revenue desc 
                                     rows between unbounded preceding 
                                              and current row) cumulative_sum
                  from (select owner, cust_id, revenue,
                               round(ratio_to_report(revenue) over(partition by owner)*100,2) pct 
                          from custrev)
               )
       )
order by owner, revenue desc;
```

Output:

```
OWNER   CUST_ID REVENUE PCT     FLAG_COL
Andy    6       1378    100     1
Emilian 1       1480000 78.08   1
Emilian 2       280160  14.78   1
Emilian 3       112486  5.93    2
Emilian 4       22903   1.21    2
Emilian 5       56      0       2
Sandy   7       560000  100     1
```

Comment: This one doesn't take into account an Owner with just 1 customer. That 1 customer will always be 100%, and should have a 1.

Comment: Changed "case when pct = 100 then 2" into "case when pct = 100 then 1".

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

OBIEE is based on models. Not on SQL.

So sorry to say this but the SQL code will help you exactly zero...